# How to access image with https in silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have SL app which is hosted on a site. In code, I want got a image from another site with https link,

So I tried to create image like:

```
image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(myUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

here myUrl is something like "https://myimagesite:port/myimage.jpg" which is different from my app host site.

It is not working. I must use non-security link like "http://myanotherimagesite:port/myimage.jpg" which is not I want.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting into a touchy subject with Silverlight in regards to access restrictions.  For an image, you are not allowed make cross scheme calls (ie if you are http, you can't call https).  Here is a link that describes the various access restrictions : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(v=vs.95).aspx